# What's the missing number in this 3x4 matrix?

Tags: pattern, calculation-puzzle

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    3 & 3 & 5 & 6 \\
    2 & 3 & 6 & 1 \\
    7 & 6 & 3 & x \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

This math puzzle is supposed to be solved by middle school students and for the life of me I cannot figure it out with certainty.

Possible answers given for `x` are: 9, 2, 7, or 8.

I know these kind of puzzles could be solved with multiple different solutions and produce various results, but what is the most obvious to you with a simple-enough pattern?

Comment: What is the puzzle exactly? Finding $x$ to fit the pattern, where what sort of "pattern" it is is unknown?

Comment: @Randal'Thor Yes, it's one of those math rebuses where one needs to find the pattern.

Comment: As [the other poster](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/112567/what-number-should-replace-the-question-mark-in-table) is not giving useful information, I try to ask here once again: @HaralanDobrev could you tell us the source of the puzzle? It doesn't look like a coincidence that two people posted the exact same puzzle at about the same time.

Comment: 9 minus 2nd row. Proves that this is an extremely lousy puzzle.

Comment: @user21820 how did you figure out that the top row was a red herring?

Comment: @rhavelka: Well, when we want a simplest solution we should actually think of simple solutions first. See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2358577/21820) to get a rough idea of what 'simple' really means from the perspective of information theory. Once we get into the habit of searching for simple solutions, we will easily find many. =)